# Linear Regression: Finding t and p-value

Tags: regression, self-study, t-test, p-value

all. I'm taking an introductory to applied statistics class and can't figure out how to do a question on my homework. I won't put all of the data up, because I really want to know how to do the problem, not just the answer.

In the problem, I am given a list of schools and the tuition from each school in the years 2000 and 2005. I put the tuition values from 2000 in list one and the values from 2005 in list two. From there, I was able to state the correct least-squares regression line by running LinReg(a+bx) on my ti-83 calculator. However, it also wants to know the p-value and t, and I have no idea how to come up with these values. We are encouraged to use our calculators, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be much obliged. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the TI-83, you can get the test statistic and the p-value by choosing
STAT->TESTS->LinRegTTest,
and then enter the required information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the ti-83, I would recommend using a full statistical program rather than a calculator if you can.  But if the calculator will give you the slope and the standard error of the slope then the t-value is just the slope divided by the standard error and then you can look up that value on the t-table (or some calculators may have that built in) to get the p-value.

Comment: The $t$ value and associated $p$ value may be for the $\beta$ coefficient, for the constant $\alpha$, or for Pearson's $r$. Basically, each of these estimated statistics, has an associated Wald-type test associated with it. The OP needs to understand _which_ $t$ and $p$ are being requested.